# What is $\mathbb E[Y\boldsymbol 1_G]$ for $G\in \sigma (Y)$?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ a probability space and $Y$ a random variable. What is $\mathbb E[Y\boldsymbol 1_G]$ for $G\in \sigma (Y)$ ?

For me, if $X,Y$ are random variable, then $$\mathbb E[XY]=\iint_{\mathbb R^2}xy\mu_{X,Y}(dx\times dy).$$
Since $G$ is $\sigma (Y)$ measurable, we can write $\boldsymbol 1_G:= f(Y)$ for $f$ a Borel function. Now, $$\mathbb E[Y\boldsymbol 1_G]=\mathbb E[f(Y)Y]=\int_{\mathbb R}yf(y)\mu_Y(dy).$$

Can we have a better formula as an integral on $\mathbb R$ ?

I know that $$\mathbb E[Y\boldsymbol 1_G]=\int_G Y\mathbb P,$$ but will we have that it's equal to $$\int_G y\mu_Y(dy)\ \ ?$$

For me it doesn't make sense since $G\subset \Omega $, not in $\mathbb R$.

I recall that $\mu_Y(dy)$ denote the probability measure induced by $Y$ on $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$
\mathbb E[Y\boldsymbol 1_G]=\int_{Y(G)} y\mu_Y({\rm d}\!y).
$$